# Select the most recent date from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a purchase order table that has a list of order numbers and associated order lines with different dates. I want to a query to fetch the orders with orderlines that has the most recent date.

[image: Order Table]

I want the fetch to result in something like below

[image: Result of my sql Query]

Comment: There is only 1 order there though, Order1, so why are you expecting 3 rows and not 1 row?

Comment: Please update your question with the TSQL you've attempted to resolve your problem and explain the problem you're encountering with your query.

Comment: Please avoid using images of tables,

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph What is the better alternative?

Comment: using plain text, it would assist in creating a sample data for testing in dbfiddle or any test database

Comment: Larnu, the reason i need 3 rows is line number has different values for each orderNumber.

Comment: Please do not post images of tables. Instead post the tables as ascii text in a code block, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) for a tool to make ascii tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using row_number

```
select * from (
select t.*
       ,row_number() over(partition by ordernumber,orderlinenumber order by date desc) as rnk
  from <your_table> t
     )x
where x.rnk=1
```

Comment: That's excellent. Works just as i wanted it. Hope it does not give me any performance issues due to usage of row_number. Thanks George.